# What is efficient way of detecting if date range of object is occupied?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm stuck and hope you can help me.

I have app for renting bikes, where user through calendar pick a date range(from startUser to endUser).Every bike has several copies(Variation), if some of the copies is available on user range,he'll take that.

i know formula: 
if not(endBike < startCar or startUser > endBike): THEY OVERLAP

and have Models like that:

```
class Bike(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Variation(models.Model):
    bike = models.ForeignKey(Bike)

class RentDate(models.Model):
    startBike= models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    endBike = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    variation = models.ForeignKey('Variation',null=True, blank=True)
```

But don't know really how to parse all dates and detect if user dates are available for one of the variation.

Thank you

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking. What are `startBike`, `endBike` and `startUser`?

Comment: Can you please explain your model. I would not expect to rent a "Variation" but a bike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need something like this:

```
available_bikes = Variation.objects.filter(...
    ).exclude(
    Q(rentdate__startCar__range=(start_date, end_date)) |
    Q(rentdate__endCar__range=(start_date, end_date))
    )
```

This will check that the rental start date and end date are not rented by other user.

after that, all  you have to do is make sure that some bikes are avilable by doing:

```
if not available_bikes:
    bikestoshow = None
else:
    bikestoshow = available_bikes[0].id #list of bike IDs
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Without this community I would not be able to finish many of my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django>=1.8, you may use  [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) for your model.

With `DurationField`, you needn't set a start_time and end_time. And by setting DurationField unique=True, you can check if this time period is occupied.

Hope helpful.

Comment: Thanks fo your answer man, but i ain't sure this field is supported by MySQL.

Comment: django's api supports all databases django supported, so this field is supported by MySQL.